# How can I clear image while saving it by using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have codes to browse image and display it, but I need another code to clear that image.

Below are my codes

```
<p><input type="file"  accept="image/*" name="image" id="file"  onchange="loadFile(event)" style="display: none;"></p>
<p><label for="file" style="cursor: pointer;">Upload Image</label></p>
<p><img id="output" width="200" /></p>
<p><input type="button" class="button default" name="send" id="upload" value="Save"></p>


<script>
var loadFile = function(event) {
    var image = document.getElementById('output');
    image.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
};
</script>
```

Actually, I save my image by using ajax, form does not load when I click the save button.

I cleared the path of the file by using the below js but it does not clear the image

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#upload").click(function(){
        var fd = new FormData();
        var files = $('#file')[0].files;
           fd.append('file',files[0]);

        if ($('#file').val()) {
            $('#file').val('');
        }

    });
});
</script>
```

How can I clear an image while saving it by using JavaScript?

Comment: You mean remove the image? Just do `$('#output').attr('src', '');` or literally `.hide()` it and `.show()` it again.

Comment: Thank you Chris, this works fine

Answer (score 0):

use like it

```
$("#file").replaceWith($("#file").val('').clone(true));
```

Comment: It does not help Murad

Comment: Sounds like OP is trying to make `<img id="output" width="200" />` not display.